# Transitioning child div when its parent is clicked

Tags: html, parent, transition

I want to have a div that is set to transition in height when the button inside it has been clicked & transition back down when the button is clicked again.

It has a child div that has a delayed transition in height after the button has been clicked. I've tried it with hover but how can I accomplish that with the click event?

Also, after both divs are at their full height, how can I make the child div transition back down before the parent div does?

Comment: Do you have any code to show you attempted this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it with `:hover`, and want to do it with a click event, use the selector `:active` - its the proper CSS selector for click events.

If you want it to change actions based on a button click, you might have to use javascript, as I don't know any way to do this with pure css. I've included code in a fiddle I found and modified for you.

### [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vLQ9/413/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $dscr = $('.description'),
    $switch = $('.toggle-link'),
    $initHeight = 40; // Initial height

$dscr.each(function() {
    $.data(this, "realHeight", $(this).height());    // Create new property realHeight
    }).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: $initHeight + 'px' });

$switch.toggle(function() {
      $dscr.animate({ height: $dscr.data("realHeight") }, 600);
      $switch.html("<button>-</button>");

    }, function() {
        $dscr.animate({ height: $initHeight}, 600);
        $switch.html("<button>+</button>");
    });
});
```